# function doesn't work with sh (but works for bash)

Tags: bash, function, sh

When I wrote a shell script with functions defined, I found I got error when using sh to execute, and get correct answer using bash. Here is a demo:

Content of test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 
function hello {
   echo "hello $1"
}
hello world
```

The output of "bash test.sh" is: hello world

The output of "sh test.sh" will give me error.

Why sh cannot get the correct answer when the script contains defined function? I didn't find an answer online. Thank you!

---

Update:
I found another issue after I get rid of "function" keyword. It turned out that in Ubuntu, sh is linked to dash. The grammar for dash is a little different from bash.

1. When defining a function, avoid using the keyword "function", this format is introduced by ksh.
2. When comparing two strings, avoid using "==". Just use "=" to compare two strings.
3. There are more changes. Please refer to the following link:

   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: The way you defined your function is not POSIX compliant (`function` is a Bash/ksh/zsh keyword but not a sh keyword). The portable way is `hello() { echo "hello $1"; }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash and sh do not share exactly the same language.

```
#!/bin/sh
hello() {
 echo "hello $1"
}

hello "world"
```

*note the absence of the `function` keyword and the `()` in the function definition.*

About the `function` keyword: [POSIX specifies that a function definition has this form](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05):

```
fname() compound-command[io-redirect ...]
```

(note that there's no `function` keyword). Moreover, in the [*Reserved Words* section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04) you'll find:

> The following words may be recognized as reserved words on some implementations (when none of the characters are quoted), causing unspecified results:
>
> `[[` `]]` `function` `select`

So if you want to have a portable function definition, don't use the `function` keyword.

Use internet to find out more, but be aware of that difference to understand how to write working script for sh.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : From man sh: [ function ] name () compound-command [redirection]
This defines a function named name. The reserved word *function* is optional.

Comment: Edited the post to include references to POSIX regarding the `function` keyword (I hope you don't mind, if you feel I damaged your post, you may rollback to a previous version).

Comment: It should also be noted that even in the context of Bash the `function` keyword is more or less deprecated and should never be used.

Comment: @Oct `man sh` is not the POSIX specification; it's the man page for whatever shell your local system uses for `/bin/sh`. `function` is probably mentioned in the spec as a nod to `ksh`, upon which the spec is largely based but in recognition that the `function` keyword is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Instructive as always :)

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I changed my script to get rid of function keyword.